# How to change the color of rows and text in aggrid on selection

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a Aggrid and have to change the color of row and text from default blue and black to green and white when we select a row in Aggrid.

I tried making use of this, but  the color of links in text does not change to white

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not related to ag-grid. All you need is to add different CSS rule for links inside a selected row, to override link color (and also, probably, `:hover`, `:active`, `:focus` states).

```
.ag-row-selected A {
  color: while;
}
```

Comment: Yup, that did the work, in my case i was rendering using button, thanks